# left and right Ore

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, monoid

A monoid $M$ satisfies the left Ore condition if for all $a,b \in M$ there exist $c,d \in M$ such that $ca=db$.  Suppose, in addition, $ac=bc$ implies that there exists an element $d \in M$ such that $da=db$. Consider the following equivalence relation $ \sim$ on $M \times M$, for all $a,b,c,d \in M$,
\begin{align}
(a,b) \sim (c,d)\hspace{0.1cm} \Leftrightarrow \exists x,y \in M \hspace{0.1cm}\text{such that}\hspace{0.1cm} xa=yc, \hspace{0.1cm}xb=yd.
\end{align}

The equivalence class of $(a,b) \in M \times M$ is denoted by $a^{-1}b$. The quotient set $$M^{-1}M=\lbrace a^{-1}b\mid a,b \in M\rbrace$$ is called the group of left fractions of $M$. This is a group for the operation 
\begin{align}
(a^{-1}b)(c^{-1}d)=(xa)^{-1}(yd),
\end{align}
where $x,y \in M$ are such that $xb=yc$, defines a group structure on $M^{-1}M$.

Similarly, $M$ satisfies the right Ore condition if for all $a,b \in M$ there exist $c,d \in M$ such that $ac=bd$. Suppose, in addition, that $ca=cb$ implies that there exists an element $d \in M$ such that $ad=bd$. Consider the equivalence relation on $M \times M$, where for all $a,b,c,d \in M$
\begin{align*}
(a,b) \sim (c,d)\hspace{0.1cm} \Leftrightarrow \exists x,y \in M \hspace{0.1cm}\text{such that}\hspace{0.1cm} ax=cy, \hspace{0.1cm}bx=dy.
\end{align*}
One then obtains a group 
$$MM^{-1}=\lbrace ab^{-1}\mid a,b \in M \rbrace,$$
for the operation
\begin{align*}
(ab^{-1})(cd^{-1})=(ax)(dy)^{-1},
\end{align*}
where $x,y \in M$ are such that $bx=cy$.

Suppose all the conditions above hold, such that one can construct both the group of left and right fractions of $M$. I'm trying to construct a straightforward group isomomorphism between $M^{-1}M$ and $MM^{-1}$, but I have trouble finding a map which preserves the group structure. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure there is an isomorphism?

Comment: Have a look: "Rings of quotients", written by Bo Stenstrom, Springer 1975

Comment: Maybe the right thing to look for is an anti-isomorphism, a map such that $f(ab)=f(b)f(a)$.